# Undefined variable of print_r

Tags: php

I got this code in php:
my purpose of $errors is to display the error when I execute them in php.
but sadly it says that $errors is not a defined variable.. how come? anybody could help me please?

```
if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true)
{
    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password';
}

else
{
    //here
}

print_r ($errors);
```

}

and I got this error..

```
Notice: Undefined variable: error in C:\xampp\htdocs\shaven\login.php on line 28
```

May I know how to solved this?

Comment: The Notice says `error`, but your vars are `$errors`. Make sure to check your spelling.

Comment: @Amal - Thanks Sir! I highly appreciate your answer.. and it works! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `$username` **and** `$password` isn't empty, then the code inside your `if` block won't be executed and `$errors` won't be defined. In that case, you'll just be trying to `print_r()` an  undefined variable.

Initialize the `$errors` with an empty array before doing the comparison:

```
$errors = array();
```

And before doing `print_r()`, make sure the array isn't empty:

```
if (!empty($errors)) {
    print_r($errors);
}
```